# ng-repeat not repeating in my angular app

Tags: angularjs

I have an array but it's only showing $scope.stocks[0]

```
{{stocks[0]}} // returns something
{{stocks[1]}} // returns another thing
{{stocks[2]}} // returns one more thing
{{stocks[3]}} // and so on...
{{stocks[4]}}
{{stocks[5]}}
<div ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
    {{stock}}  // only repeats one time. Returns stock[0]
</div>
```

Here's some additional code:

```
    window.google = {
        visualization: {
            Query: {
                setResponse: function (a) {
                        $scope.stocks = Array;
                    for (var i = 0; i < a.table.rows.length; i = i + 1){
                        $scope.stocks[i] = a.table.rows[i].c;
                        console.log(a.table.rows[i].c);
                        console.log($scope.stocks[i]);

                    }
                    console.log('Stocks are',$scope.stocks);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here's some console logs

```
stocks.js:22 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:23 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:19 hi2
stocks.js:22 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:23 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:19 hi2
stocks.js:22 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:23 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:19 hi2
stocks.js:22 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:23 [Object, Object]
stocks.js:26 Stocks are function Array() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Please provide additional code, there is not enough to go on at the moment.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll provide some additional code.

Comment: Please show the console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$scope.stocks = new Array()
```

against

```
$scope.stock = Array
```

It is because you bind function to your stocks not array object